# Get attributes and values using SimpleXML

Tags: php, attributes, simplexml

I really don't understand how to use SimpleXML in PHP.

Here is an exemple of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<eventlog version="1.1">

<event source="Firewall" timeStamp="1308433939" type="0" deleted="0" bodyLength="218">
<subject>Network access detected</subject>
<action>Allowed</action>
<message>The program c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe attempted to connect to the Internet. The program used the protocol TCP on port 80.</message>
</event>

</eventlog>
```

I need to retrieve this:
Source, Timestamp, Subject, Action, Message

I just don't get it. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Question is question and answer is answer. I moved your edit into an answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14194288/367456 - You can do the same (from visiting the history of your question) if you like, I will then remove my copy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This code should work:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
$source = $xml->event->attributes()->source;
$timestamp = $xml->event->attributes()->timestamp;
$subject = $xml->event->subject;
$action = $xml->event->action;
$message = $xml->event->message;
```

... where $xmlString is the string of the xml file.

Read up on how to use simpleXML [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Hope this helped and good luck!

Comment: Woah! I didn't think about that! Thanks! But i have multiple 'event' tag, :S so i just put it between foreach loop?

Comment: If you want to get all of the subject, action, and messages under all of the event tags, then yea, just use a foreach loop. If you just want to get a specific one of the events, use event[0], event[1], etc. Glad I helped!

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of *teaching you to fish*, I'd encourage you to check out the [PHP Docs on SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

To help get your started though.

1. Use `simplexml_load_file()` or `simplexml_load_string()` to parse your XML
2. This will return an object - use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` to see what it looks like.
3. Traverse this object to obtain the attributes you want.

Comment: Yep thanks, I already read this docs... But I'll try using var_dump and with multiple try i should be able to get what I want. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
function time2DatetimeUS($timestamp)
{
  $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
  return $datetime;
}

$db = new SQLiteDatabase("AutoAnalysis.sqlite", 0666, $err);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($logs_antivirus_local, NULL, TRUE);
foreach ($xml->event as $a) {
    $source    = $a->attributes()->source;
    $timestamp = $a->attributes()->timeStamp;
    $datetime  = time2DatetimeUS("$timestamp");
    $subject   = $a->subject;
    $action    = $a->action;
    $message   = $a->message;
}

$query = "INSERT INTO BitDefender(id, datetime, module, sujet, action, message) 
                VALUES ('', '$datetime', '$source', '$subject', '$action', '$message')";
$results = $db->queryexec($query);
echo "     $datetime     $source  $subject";
```